# How to calculate the series‘ ’convergence and divergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

1.$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{i^n}{n}$

2.$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1+i)^n}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}\sin in}$

Let $c_{n}$ the original series.

**For 1**, what I think is that use $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|\;c_{n+1}\;|}{|\;c_{n}\;|}$$
But the modulus of $c_{n}$ is not definite. So must I make a categorized discussion about n?

**For 2**, I want to use$$\lim_{n \to \infty}|{\;c_{n}\;|^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$
But it becomes$$\lim_{n \to \infty} e(\frac{2}{e^{2n}-1}) ^{\frac{1}{n} }$$
It seems that I must change n to x and then use the L'Hospital's Rule.

Is there a better solution for them? Hope you can help me! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first series converges by the Dirichlet test: the sequence $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is monotonic and convergent to $0$ and, for each $N\in\Bbb N$,$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^Ni^n\right|=\left|\frac{i-i^{N+1}}{1-i}\right|\leqslant\frac2{\sqrt2}=\sqrt2.$$Concerning the second series, note that, for each $n\in\Bbb N$,\begin{align}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{(1+i)^n}{2^{n/2}\sin(in)}\right|}&=\sqrt[n]{\frac{2^{n/2}}{2^{n/2}\sinh(n)}}\\&=\frac1{\sqrt[n]{\frac{e^n-e^{-n}}{2}}}\to e^{-1}<1,\end{align}and therefore your series converges, by the root test.

Comment: But for 2's final limit,$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{e^n-e^{-n}}{2}}$$ \\ Its limit should use the **the L'Hospital's Rule** after changing n with x which is continous ?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]2=1$?

Comment: Thank you very much! I have solved it now.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.